# Clearing screen on petite chez scheme

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

A little question that bothers me.
Does anyone knows how to clear the screen on petite chez scheme SWL? 
I have tried clear, cls ,clean .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This document http://scheme.com/csug8/use.html says:

```
^L-^L   clear screen and redisplay entry
```

If you want to clear the screen from a program send the "clear screen" code used by your terminal. In https://github.com/tonyg/racket-ansi/blob/master/ansi.rkt you see that the code sent is CSI "2J" where CSI stands for \033[

Here is how to do it from a program (tested in Petite in terminal on OS X).

```
(define ESC #\033)
(define CSI (list->string (list ESC #\[ )))
(define CLEAR (string-append CSI "2J"))
(display CLEAR)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . However ,ctrl L - ctrl L not working and the link you sent is in racket scheme and not in chez scheme

Comment: What do you mean? The scheme.com link is clearly foo Chez Scheme. The other link lists ANSI sequences (i.e. character sequences that are sent to the terminal) - the file happens to be written in Racket, but the point was to show you how to find the code CSI 2J. 

Anyways - did you want to clear the screen from the keyboard or from a program?  Also important which terminal do you run Chez Sheme in? (terminal in OS X, xterm in Linux or ...)

Comment: I meant the second link.Windows . I have tried to put the code in the second link in petite chez scheme swl but got errors because some of the code used in this link is racket scheme related only . Have you tried to use it ?

Comment: The code wasn't the point - the control sequence was. You run Chez Scheme in a terminal. The terminal handles what to display on the screen. If a program sends a specific control code the terminal clears the screen. For an ANSI terminal you need to display esc, [, 2, J. This sequence is the same for all programming languages including Chez Scheme and Racket. I have added an example and tested it with Chez Petite in an OS X terminal.

Comment: I isnt working for me, it just open interaction window and shows ←[2J

Comment: At this point we can conclude, that your terminal doesn't listen to ANSI codes. Maybe you will get a better answer on the Chez Scheme mailing list (I hope there is one?)?